# Mathematical golfing

Tags: mathematics

You have probably heard of code golfing? There the task is to find the shortest computer program that produces the required output. Here we want to perform math golfing - find the shortest formula that produces a given number. The length of a formula is measured as the number of characters. The format must be as follows:

- Contain only digits '0' to '9' and characters '+' (addition), '-' (subtraction), '*' (multiplication), '^' (exponentiation), brackets '(' and ')'.
- Digits can be concatenated such as 567.
- Operations have precedence, like in BODMAS. Brackets are done first, followed by exponentiation, followed by multiplication, followed by addition/subtraction (from left to right).
- For example (10^2+1)*2^5 is equivalent to (100+1)*32 = 3232. The formula uses 12 characters, so it is not a compact representation of the result that has 4 characters.

Find the shortest formulas that represent the following numbers:

1. 99999999999
2. 41601569625
3. 61917364165
4. 82644187136
5. 33059881770
6. 12345678901234
7. 10101010101010
8. 33333333333333
9. 68945723674934237482
10. 5782934283492912347898237400000
11. 34828517376

Comment: Partial answers are accepted too!

Comment: "from left to right" breaks the default priority of  $a^{b^c} = a^{(b^c)}$, though.

Comment: Is a unary minus allowed?

Comment: Jens yeah why not. Any attempts at the missing numbers?

Comment: I have decided to add brackets to make things a bit more interesting, especially for those larger terms. The current answer is still valid.

Comment: Can we do anything for the remaining unsolved numbers?

Answer (score 6):

I'm still missing a few of the answers.

99999999999 = (7 characters)

> 10^11-1

41601569625 = (6 characters)

> 3465^3

61917364165 = (8 characters)

> 12^10-59

82644187136 = (6 characters)

> 4*14^9

33059881770 = (9 characters)

> 3*18^8+42

12345678901234 = ?

10101010101010 = ?

33333333333333 = ?
I had an 11-character solution but that used division (10^14/3-1/3).

68945723674934237482 = ?

5782934283492912347898237400000 = ?

34828517376 = (5 characters, Thanks to Ben J in the comments)

> 432^4

Comment: Very nice Jaap! You have matched my best results and improved some of them.

Comment: For the last number, it's possible to golf another 2 characters by rearranging to remove an operator.

Comment: Great observation Ben!